# Cannot find module error while Lazy loading

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module

I want to setup **lazy loading** for my modules, but there is an error I can't solve.

The error is:

> core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find
>   module 'app/invoice-builder/invoice-builder.module' Error: Cannot find
>   module 'app/invoice-builder/invoice-builder.module'

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'invoice-builder',
    loadChildren : 'app/invoice-builder/invoice-builder.module#InvoiceBuilderModule'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'invoice-builder'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { MaterialModule } from './shared/material.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I can't understand what happen in here. I tried twice to restart the project using
`npm start` but, that did not work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try add your component also into declarations section.

Comment: yes i tried using ./app/invoice-builder/invoice-builder.module#InvoiceBuilderModule but not success

Comment: yes i added component into declaration as you told , but nothing happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is probably due to the way you defined your path.

From the official angular docs on [Lazy Loading Modules](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

> Notice that the lazy loading syntax uses loadChildren followed by a string that is the relative path to the module, a hash mark or #, and the module’s class name.

Try updating your path to:

`loadChildren : './app/invoice-builder/invoice-builder.module#InvoiceBuilderModule'`

or depending on your file structure you may not need the `./app` in which case you could try

`loadChildren : './invoice-builder/invoice-builder.module#InvoiceBuilderModule'`

Comment: I modified the code as you told (loadChildren : './invoice-builder/invoice-builder.module#InvoiceBuilderModule'), afterward console errors are disappear. but there is no any output . output shold be " invoice-builder works!"

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue when worked with **Angular 9** and managed to fixed it by using this syntax that [found in docs:](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: () => import('./customers/customers.module').then(m => m.CustomersModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then(m => m.OrdersModule)
  }
];
```

Comment: Your correct! They´ve breakdown Angular on Ng11... You have to go the 'old days'

Answer (score 0):

Update the LoadChieldren path like ,

```
loadChildren : './invoice-builder/invoice-builder.module#InvoiceBuilderModule'
```

Because the invoice-builder folder is inside the app folder.
And the app-routing.module.ts is also in the same directory so update the path of module.